# createHtmlOutput() not work in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a Script in about 1yr before.
Today when I run it again, the command HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLToOutput) seems not longer work, with this error shown on my Chrome (which hasn't disallowed Javascript):
"The current browser does not support this feature. Please upgrade to a newer browser."

My code is standard code inside doGet(e). Even this simplified version won't work also:

```
function doGet(e) {
  ...
  HTMLToOutput = "<html><h1>Install this App into your Google Drive!</h1><a href='" + getURLForAuthorization() + "'>click here to start</a></html>";
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLToOutput).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getURLForAuthorization() {
  return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?response_type=code&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URL +   '&scope=' + AUTH_SCOPE;
}
```

Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: Hi @pat I am also getting same error for script that I have created 6 months before. I don't know what is going on back end?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by adding this

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

so, total line should look like this:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLToOutput).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Comment: Thanks! This let me show the content successfully, but I doubt that this also cause the following problem and block my hyperlink inside the created HTML content. As a result, when I clicked on "click here to start", it gives no response. My full script was a popular one for passing OAuth2: